# Is there an easy way to parse a float from a string in C++ GNU ARM embedded?

Tags: c++, parsing, arm, embedded, gnu

I have this string in my C++ GNU ARM embedded system:

```
char* TempStr = "pressure 0.85";
```

I need the number value stored as a separate float variable called presmax.

Up until now the number to be parsed has always been an integer, so I could use sscanf without any issues. However, as I have read about extensively on the web (and experienced first hand), sscanf doesn't typically work on floats in embedded systems (without some extensive configuration/loss of flash space).

I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions. Perhaps I could parse the "0.85" as a char array? I'm not quite sure how to do that, though it would allow me to use atof() to turn it into a float, as I've done elsewhere in the program.

I realize the other option is to write a function, however I'm quite an amateur programmer so if there's a more robust/time effective solution I'd best take it.

**UPDATE:**
In case it helps, TempStr is a string copied from a .txt file on an SD card using FatFs. Here's the full code that reads two lines and stores the results in TempStr each time. I parse the string into its respective variable each time TempStr is stored:

```
FILINFO fno;
FIL fsrc;
int FileEnd = 0;
int CurrentLine = 0;
int pressmax = 0;
int timemax = 0;
char* TempStr;
WCHAR CharBuffer[100];

res = f_stat("config.txt", &fno);                               //check for config.txt file
res = f_open(&fsrc, "config.txt", FA_READ | FA_OPEN_ALWAYS);    //open config.txt file

//first line
TempStr = f_gets((char*)CharBuffer, sizeof(fsrc), &fsrc);      
CurrentLine ++;
FileEnd = FileEnd + strlen(TempStr) + 1;

//sscanf(TempStr, "%*s %i", &presmax);       //what I did when presmax was an int

//second line
while ((f_eof(&fsrc) == 0)){                                   
        TempStr = f_gets((char*)CharBuffer, sizeof(fsrc), &fsrc);
        CurrentLine ++;
        FileEnd = FileEnd + strlen(TempStr) + 1;
}

//sscanf(TempStr, "%*s %i", &timemax);
```

Using GNU ARM Build tools on an STM32L w/Eclipse.

Comment: What is the type of `TempStr`?  You should just be able to get a pointer to the first digit and then pass that to `atof`.

Comment: TempStr is a char*. It's a string line copied from a .txt file on an SD card using FatFs. I'll edit the question above to include that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are guaranteed that your input will be in the form of

```
text floating_point_number
```

then once you have `TempStr` you can advance a pointer through it until you reach the space, and then go one position further to get to the floating point part of the string.  Then you pass that pointer to `atof` to get the value out of the remainder of string.  That would look like

```
char* fp = TempStr;
while (*fp != ' ') ++fp; // get to the space
double value = atof(++fp); // advance to floating point part and pass to atof
```

If you don't need `TempStr` after you get the value then you can get rid of `fp` and just use

```
while (*TempStr != ' ') ++TempStr ; // get to the space
double value = atof(++TempStr); // advance to floating point part and pass to atof
```

Comment: That certainly works for now. Thanks a lot... I will have to revisit this as the project progresses (and my skills improve) however to try and figure something out that doesn't depend on a perfect input (in case someone types the config.txt lines wrong). If anyone has any suggestions I'd love to hear them. That was the benefit of sscanf, it could look past the garbage and the just take the numbers.

Comment: @Zurn For that, if you just want to extract the floating point number then you can scan through the line until you find a `.`.  Then you go forward and back from there until you run you hit non-numeric characters.  Then copy that into its own buffer and pass it to `atof`.  Do note that there is no 100% bullet proof way to accept any arbitrary input.  Sometimes you'll just have to issue an error and end processing, or fall back to some default value and log that you have done so.

Comment: Advancing past the space is unnecessary `atof()` skips leading whitespace.  A minor point is that the question asks for the value in a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follows:

```
float presmax = (float)atof( strchr( TempStr, ' ' ) ;
```

The cast is only necessary because your question specifically asks for `float` and `atof()` returns a `double`.  The cast would be implicit in any event, so:

```
float presmax = atof( strchr( TempStr, ' ' ) ;
```

is also acceptable.

`strchr()` returns a pointer to the first space character, and `atof()` ignores any leading space.  If your config file might use a TAB character, then:

```
float presmax = (float)atof( strpbrk( TempStr, " \t" ) ;
```

It will fail if either `strchr()` or `strpbrk()` return NULL when the delimiter is not found, so you might make it more robust thus:

```
#define PRESMAX_DEFAULT 1.0f

const char* prestr = strchr( TempStr ) ;
float presmax = prestr == NULL ? PRESMAX_DEFAULT : (float)atof( prestr ) ;
```